# MyFirstApp tutorial Android Studio -- sendMessage Issue

Tags: java, android

So I just started to learn Android Studio for android development and started going through the myFirstApp tutorial on their website.  I am trying to add a method to the button but can't get it to work.  I have the sendMessage method in MainActivity.java and when i go to select it from the "on click" drop down list, it doesn't appear.  I have the correct imports as well. Does anyone know why this may be? Thanks.

Here is what my code looks like:

```
package com.example.tyler.myfirstapp;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    /** Called when the user taps the Send button */
    public void sendMessage(View view) {
    // Do something in response to button
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to declare your `sendMessage` in the layout xml. E.g. `android:onClick = "sendMessage"`.

Comment: Okay, Thanks! That worked. Not sure why it doesn't say that in the tutorial.

Comment: @Enzokie I am running into the same issue. The tutorial is pretty clear that that the only step required is to add the sendMessage method to the MainActivity class and that the popup should be automatically populated after that. It is not, and it is unclear if the tutorial is missing a step or if this is a bug in Android Studio. (I'm using Kotlin but I see the same problem)

Comment: @StefanArentz You need to manually add it because Android Studio cannot inferred which `View` is the *implicit* listener belongs for the case of multiple `Views` present in your xml (I would say this is not a bug but a limitation in the IDE). I kinda agree that the docs is sometimes confusing and incomplete.

Answer (score 2):

Add `android:onClick="sendMessage"` attribute to your button tag in activity_main.xml.

From the [tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html) you are following:

> Now return to the activity_main.xml file to call this method from the button:
>
> 1. Click to select the button in the Layout Editor.
> 2. In the Properties window, locate the onClick property and select sendMessage [MainActivity] from the drop-down list.

You must've skipped this step.

Comment: This is incorrect. Android Studio is supposed to automatically populate that popup with methods that it finds in the activity. You should not have to add it in the XML manually.

Comment: The method doesn't automatically pop up, which is the issue. Same here!

Comment: Same problem with the tutorial here. Your suggestion worked out well.

Answer (score 0):

I got stuck with this one as well, so i skipped down the page a bit and grabbed the complete code for MainActivity.java (apart from the first line that i kept).
Once i'd replaced this i got the sendMessage[MainActivity] appear on the onClick Button attribute.

```
package com.example.your....

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

/** Called when the user taps the Send button */
public void sendMessage(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    String message = editText.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
    startActivity(intent);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer for this is that you do not have the function INSIDE of the last curly brace at the bottom. Just undo the function you pasted and make sure to repaste just before the last curly brace and then it will all be fixed.